# SBT: "value map is not a member of (sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Tests.Output], sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Tests.Output]) " when updating from 0.13.8 to 1.x.x

Tags: scala, sbt

I've below sbt-mult-jvm plugin which are working fine on sbt version 0.13.18.

```
    import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtMultiJvm
    import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtMultiJvm.MultiJvmKeys.MultiJvm

    lazy val rootProject = (project in file("."))
    .settings(executeTests in IntegrationTest <<= (executeTests in Test, executeTests in MultiJvm) map {
    case (testResults, multiNodeResults)  =>
        val overall =
        if (testResults.overall.id < multiNodeResults.overall.id)
            multiNodeResults.overall
        else
            testResults.overall
        Tests.Output(overall,
        testResults.events ++ multiNodeResults.events,
        testResults.summaries ++ multiNodeResults.summaries)
    }).
    configs(IntegrationTest, MultiJvm)
```

But when I updated the sbt version to 1.x.x using this migration [guide](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html)

```
    import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtMultiJvm
    import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtMultiJvm.MultiJvmKeys.MultiJvm

    lazy val rootProject = (project in file("."))
    .settings(executeTests in IntegrationTest := (( executeTests in Test, executeTests in MultiJvm).value) map {
    case (testResults, multiNodeResults)  =>
        val overall =
        if (testResults.overall.id < multiNodeResults.overall.id)
            multiNodeResults.overall
        else
            testResults.overall
        Tests.Output(overall,
        testResults.events ++ multiNodeResults.events,
        testResults.summaries ++ multiNodeResults.summaries)
    }).
    configs(IntegrationTest, MultiJvm)
```

I'm getting below error.

```
    [info] Done updating.
    [warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
    /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/akka-zk-cluster-seed/build.sbt:87: error: `<<=` operator is removed. Use `key := { x.value }` or `key ~= (old => { newValue })`.
    See http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html
    settings(compile in MultiJvm <<= (compile in MultiJvm) triggeredBy (compile in IntegrationTest)).
                                ^
    /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/akka-zk-cluster-seed/build.sbt:88: error: value map is not a member of (sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Tests.Output], sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Tests.Output])
    settings(executeTests in IntegrationTest <<= (executeTests in Test, executeTests in MultiJvm) map {
                                                                                                    ^
    /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/akka-zk-cluster-seed/build.sbt:91: error: value overall is not a member of Any
            if (testResults.overall.id < multiNodeResults.overall.id)
                            ^
    /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/akka-zk-cluster-seed/build.sbt:91: error: value overall is not a member of Any
            if (testResults.overall.id < multiNodeResults.overall.id)
                                                        ^
    /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/akka-zk-cluster-seed/build.sbt:92: error: value overall is not a member of Any
            multiNodeResults.overall
                            ^
    /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/akka-zk-cluster-seed/build.sbt:94: error: value overall is not a member of Any
            testResults.overall
                        ^
    /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/akka-zk-cluster-seed/build.sbt:96: error: value events is not a member of Any
            testResults.events ++ multiNodeResults.events,
                        ^
    /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/akka-zk-cluster-seed/build.sbt:96: error: value events is not a member of Any
            testResults.events ++ multiNodeResults.events,
                                                ^
    /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/akka-zk-cluster-seed/build.sbt:97: error: value summaries is not a member of Any
            testResults.summaries ++ multiNodeResults.summaries)
                        ^
    /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/akka-zk-cluster-seed/build.sbt:97: error: value summaries is not a member of Any
            testResults.summaries ++ multiNodeResults.summaries)
                                                    ^
    [error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
    [error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the [link](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html#Migrating+from+sbt+0.12+style) you provide; specifically "the tuple enrichments (apply and map) for TaskKey’s" has been removed.

The replacement is to use `.value`, which removes the need for the map.

Your project should look something like this (untested):

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtMultiJvm
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtMultiJvm.MultiJvmKeys.MultiJvm

lazy val rootProject = (project in file("."))
  .settings(executeTests in IntegrationTest := {
      val testResults = (executeTests in Test).value
      val multiNodeResults = (executeTests in MultiJvm).value
      val overall = if (testResults.overall.id < multiNodeResults.overall.id)
          multiNodeResults.overall
        else
          testResults.overall
      Tests.Output(overall,
      testResults.events ++ multiNodeResults.events,
      testResults.summaries ++ multiNodeResults.summaries)
    })
  .configs(IntegrationTest, MultiJvm)
```

Comment: I'm getting the error -  `error: value id is not a member of sbt.protocol.testing.TestResult
      val overall = if (testResults.overall.id < multiNodeResults.overall.id)`

Comment: Looks like the `TestResult` is no longer an `Enumeration`, it seems to be an ADT consisting of `Passed`, `Failed`, `Error`. You are going to have to write your own code to merge the result here, comparing each case.